# Graphics Corruption ubuntu 15.04 with propietary flgrx-update drivers

Tags: ati, 15.04, fglrx

i'm kind of new to linux. I'm running 15.04 on a single boot. (I erased all HD accidentally testing several distros XO )

I have a new HP Pavilion Notebook – 15-p244no

Apparently this notebook has two Graphic cards:

- AMD HD 8610G
- AMD Radeon R7 M260

The problem is that using open source graphics driver I cant turn the dedicated graphics off so This computer gets really hot and fans are at max. Have disabled "fans always on" setting in the bios also.

Using the fglrx or fglrx-update propietary driver (well actually AMD control center...) I can choose the integrated card and fans and temperature are ok. But I get graphics corruption on chrome, as far as I see just chrome. See pic attached.

http://i62.tinypic.com/oisqe1.jpg

I attach also information about my drivers installed and all.

http://i57.tinypic.com/fjer6b.png

I activated the vivid-proposed updates also to see if there were some beta driver but there wasnt.

Any help would be appreciated.

PD: sorry but I cant upload images directly due to lack of reputation.

Update: Oh I remember that streaming videos on fullscreen on chrome gives strange flashes and sometimes cant stop video or minimize video or anything till video finishes.